# Get datepicker to return specific time of day

Tags: extjs, extjs4

**ExtJS 4.2.2**

I have this datefield with the format

```
d-m-Y H:i:s
```

I would like the datepicker to return the selected date with a specific time - 07:00 (7AM). So that if I pick today it would return

```
17-09-2014 07:00:00
```

and not as it does now

```
17-09-2014 00:00:00
```

I've tried to find a configuration but it's just not obvious to me if there is one...

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handled it using the 'select' event:

```
select: function(field, value, eOpts){
    field.setValue(new Date(value.setHours(7,0,0)))
}
```